# Is there a way to use "sister" function implementation in a class derived from an abstract class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a design issue. I'd like to use a function implementation from a "sister" class when deriving from an abstract class if it is possible.

## Problem

I have some "historic" code that adds a behavior to a base class using inheritance.

### Old code

```
///////////////// Historic code ////////////////:

class IBase
{
    int value;
    virtual int method(){
        return value;
    };
}

class DerivedHist : IBase {
    void otherMethod(){
        return;
    }
}
```

### New code

After some modifications, I ended up specializing the IBase in 2 derived classes (Derived1 and Derived2), and changed the IBase class to an abstract class.
The problem is that I'd like to add the DerivedHist class behavior to both classes, and I don't see how to do it in a good way.

```
///////////////////// New code //////////////////////////:

//this time IBase is an abstract class
class IBase
{
    int value;
    virtual int method() = 0;
}

class DerivedHist : IBase {
    void otherMethod(){
        return;
    }

    //I'd like to use Derived1's or Derived2's implementation
    virtual int method(){
        //???
    }
}

class Derived1 : IBase {
    virtual int method(){
        return 2*value;
    }
}

class Derived2 : IBase {
    virtual int method(){
        return 3*value;
    }
}
```

I don't see exactly how to put back the DerivedHist class in place...

## Solutions

I came up with some ideas:

1. Write 2 classes equivalent to DerivedHist that inherit from Derived1 (say Derived1Hist) and from Derived2 (say Derived2Hist), 
   but that means having two classes with almost the same code.

   ```
                                   IBase
                                   /   \
                           Derived1    Derived2
                           /               \
                       Derived1Hist        Derived2Hist
   ```
2. Using something like this in the DerivedHist constructor:

   ```
   DerivedHist(IBase* other) : IBase(*other){
       ...
   }
   ```

   and call it with a dynamic cast:

   ```
   Derived1 derived1(...);
   DerivedHist derivedHist(dynamic_cast<IBase*>(derived1));
   ```

   Wouldn't this use the correct implementation of method() ? As we can call dynamic_cast(new Derived1(...))->method() I imagined that passing something like this in a copy constructor could work.
   I couldn't find a way to have the code compiling with something like this...
3. Have one of the Derived[1,2] object as a member

   ```
   class DerivedHist : IBase {
       IBase* methodHolder;

       DerivedHist(IBase* other) : methodHolder(other){
           ...
       }

       void otherMethod(){
           return;
       }

       virtual int method(){
           //here I'd have to copy the relevant data members to the other object
           methodHolder->value = value;
           //and then call the other method
           return methodHolder->method();
       }
   }
   ```

   This looks like the best solution of the 3.

   But here the problem that I see is that I have not the data synced from DerivedHist and its methodHolder member.

   I could keep track of every changes and apply it to methodHolder but this does not seem to be the perfect solution.

## Summary

To summarize, the two main questions I have are the following:

1. Is there a way to call an implementation of method() from another
   derived class ?
2. Otherwise, what kind of pattern should I use to solve this issue ?

Comment: In solution 3, `methodHolder` and `other` (in the constuctor) need to be pointers (or references) to avoid [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/5231607).